# I'm trying to create a vbs file that will create a shortcut for another batch file on the desktop but I can't get it right

Tags: vbscript

I'm very new to vb script and need some help here is my code so far and this is all inside a folder with another folder inside named "Loops" I wanted the shortcut to also start in that directory along with it being on the desktop but what happens is nothing shows up and I don't know what to do

```
Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next

Private WshShell
Private strDesktop
Private oShellLink

set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strDesktop = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")

set oShellLink = WshShell.CreateShortcut(strDesktop , "TTS.lnk")
oShellLink.TargetPath = "Loops\TTS.vbs"
oShellLink.IconLocation = "notepad.exe, 1"
oShellLink.WorkingDirectory = "Loops"
oShellLink.Save
```

Comment: Use absolute paths.

Comment: It wouldn't work it were on someone else's computer I want to be able to send it as a zip and make shortcuts for batch files on their desktops @AnsgarWiechers

Comment: place your loops folder under the user profile which is also a special folder and reference to it like that, or simpler just use a batch instead of a shortcut and use %USERPROFILE%\loops\my_vbs_or_batch_to_start